# How to select a div in a div which is in active page(div) while using attr event?

Tags: jquery

I got this:

```
$(".containers").not(':first').hide(); 
$("#topbar ul li a").click(function() {
    var activeLink = $(this).attr("href"); 
    $("#topbar ul li a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
    $(".containers").hide();
    $(activeLink).show();
    return false;
});
```

My question here is how can select(call) a div in the active container?
Let's say I am trying to animate box3 as the container3 header link is clicked or box2 as the container2 header link is clicked and so on...

You can see it beter here: http://jsfiddle.net/JWBQG/

Comment: can't see problem with you fiddle. you just want to add animation? what kind?

Comment: There is not a problem with the codes.. I just want to be able to add animation to the box which is in the active(selected) container...

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding correctly. See my answer and let me know if I'm on the right track.

Comment: I'll try like that: How can I animate box3 as I click on container3 link?

Comment: So you want the respective .container_box to animate when its header link is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/JWBQG/6

```
var myIndex = $(this).parent('li').index();
$('.containers').eq(myIndex).find('.container_box').slideToggle().slideToggle();
```